# Multi-language Category Titles in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

just looking for a bit of advice.

Summary for those who don't want to read it all: Is creating a table with just one single auto_increment column a reasonable idea?

Details:

I normally manage multiple languages in the database, with separate tables for the object's data and its descriptions in language. For example:

```
Table: MyObject (id auto_increment, height, width, depth. PK = id)
Table: MyObjectDescription (id, language, description. PK = id, language)
```

The two id fields correspond, so I have data like:

```
MyObject
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id | height | width | depth |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     10 |    10 |    20 |
|  2 |      5 |     6 |     7 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+

MyObjectDescription
+----+----------+-----------------+
| id | language | description     |
+----+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | EN       | First object    |
|  1 | IT       | Primo Oggetto   |
|  2 | EN       | Second object   |
|  2 | IT       | Secondo Oggetto |
+----+----------+-----------------+
```

My problem is that I have certain database objects which have ***no*** data ***apart from*** the description.

**For example**; a Category is defined simply as an id and a text description. I could use a single table like the MyObjectDescription table, but then I would have to generate the id myself, as I wouldn't be able to make use of the auto_increment column. This would also raise the possibility of *race condition errors*, or *table locking problems*. Or, I could use another table like MyObject which just has a single auto_increment column...

**my doubt is:** Is using a table with a single column just to simulate a sequence a reasonable idea? Or is it just plain stupid? Be aware also that my framework contains logic that automatically joins the object table to the description table.

Thanks for any input/ideas.

Gareth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MyObject (id)`.

Unless you have these objects in isolation from the rest of the database, you will need the PK comprised from `id` **alone**, so it can be referenced by FOREIGN KEYs.

Even in isolation, the enforcement of key would justify the separate table. Without it, you'd have to somehow generate a new `id` while preventing concurrent transactions from generating the same `id` for a different object. Obvious way to do it would be to lock the whole table (and select MAX+1), but that destroys scalability. It's better to just have a separate table, IMO. If  you [cluster](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) it under InnoDB, that'll be just a single B-Tree anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - It confirms what I was thinking. Thanks for the link too - I didn't know about this aspect, and will look into it.