# Multilingual database - Get all languages of post

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, translation, multilingual

I want to write an application where multilingual data is stored in a database. There are posts with an unique ID which are written in several languages (at least 2 languages, other languages will possibly be added). I already looked through several posts of stackoverflow and found these nearly satisfying answers:
[Multi-language Category Titles in Mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625183/multi-language-category-titles-in-mysql-database)
[What's the best database structure to keep multilingual data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227985/whats-the-best-database-structure-to-keep-multilingual-data)
[Schema for a multilanguage database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database)

They all suggest to put up 3 tables like this:

```
[ languages ]
id (INT)
name (VARCHAR)

[ products ]
id (INT)
price (DECIMAL)

[ translation ]
id (INT, PK)
model (VARCHAR) // product
field (VARCHAR) // name
language_id (INT, FK) 
text (VARCHAR)
```

(This is from one of the links above)

I agree with that solution, but I want the application to show all the possible languages the post is written in. I already thought of reading all the translations for a post and using only one to create the page, but use the other translations to show other possible languages. I don't like this idea, because that way I retrieve too much data from the database that isn't used (because I retrieve many translations an use only one).
I also thought of retrieving all possible translations and storing them already in the page (e.g. in javascript code, in a data-attribute, etc.), but this would make the page slower, because I think most users only want to see the post in only one language.
So I guess the application has to execute 2 queries: one to get the translation and one to get all languages for the post. But I think there is a way to put this in one query, but I don't have a good idea how to do that.

Is there a easy way to read the translation for a language (given by the user or default, maybe just the first database entry) and all other language the post is written in with just a single query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use two queries for higher flexibility.

Also you can use one query - for example to get languages separated by "," in a string:

```
SELECT t.*,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l1.name SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM translation t1
    JOIN languages l1 ON l1.id = t1.language_id
    WHERE t1.product_id = t.product_id
    GROUP BY t1.product_id
  ) AS lang_names
FROM translation t
  -- there put required JOIN-s --
  WHERE t.id = ?
```

there: **?** is placeholder for translation id which you wish to show.
I assume there is **product_id** field in the **translation** table.